# How to look back the last position when viewing source code in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

The Qt Creator has provided easy way to develop `C++` projects for us. When viewing the source code, we could click the `Shift` key and the left key of the mouse to see the detail implementation of the function. But when we have seen the code, how could I look back the last position we clicked before and viewing the code from that position?

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-keyboard-shortcuts.html
Go back - `Alt+Left`
Go forward - `Alt+Right`
You can also change these shortcuts in the settings menu.

Comment: @Dmitry why you didn't post this as an answer?

Comment: @Dmitry, thank you. Absolutely right.